# How to create pseudo-spectogram using numpy

Tags: numpy, data-visualization

I have a data series of about 50,000 points. Say it's roughly 60Hz, but not perfectly regular, for about 15 minutes. I would like to do a visualization like it [this writeup](https://sysdigcloud.com/aws-storage-latency-sysdig-spectrogram/).

So I want to divide up the data into slices and then perform a histogram on each slice, then visualize the histogram using some colormap. So if I wanted 10 second bins I would need to compute about 90 different histograms. If it was 1 second bins it would be 900 histograms. Is there a way to do this efficiently? I was thinking just numpy.where and numpy.histogram for each slice but I'm wondering if that will be slow. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you already look matplotlib. It can do spectograms: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram If your data is not uniformly sampled, usually resampling it with ``scipy.interpolate.interp1d()`` does the trick

Comment: I did see that matplotlib does them. I was planning to make my own D3 viz and not use matplib, because I wanted a bunch of interactions not just a static image.  There is something mpld3 which claims to convert from matplotlib to D3 I don't really understand how that works yet, I could try.